# List index out of range error

Tags: python, list

Keeps on getting index out of range error when I run this code how do i solve this? The data contains a few values that would be passed down to the valueList through a server and i would like to use a part of those values in the data. For example , int(valueList[8]) contains the x coordinate of the ball. how do I solve this issue?

```
import os,sys
import pygame
import socket
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
from ctypes import c_bool

Host = '59.191.193.45'
Port = 5555

def updatePosition(valueList, update_valueList, quit_flag):
    while not quit_flag.value:
        print 'Ball x', int(valueList[8])
        print 'Ball y', int(valueList[9])
        update_valueList = valueList[:]
    print 'Closing child update process'

def activateRobot(update_valueList, quit_flag): 
    while not quit_flag.value:
        print 'Ball x', int(valueList[8])
        print 'Ball y', int(valueList[9])
        print 'turn to'
        print 'move to', int(valueList[8])
        print 'move to', int(valueList[9])
    print 'Closing child activate robot process'

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((Host,Port))

valueList = []
update_valueList = []
quit_flag = Value(c_bool,False)

update = Process(target = updatePosition, args=(valueList, update_valueList,quit_flag))
activate = Process(target = activateRobot, args=(update_valueList,quit_flag))

update.start()
activate.start()

while True:
    client.sendall("loc\n")
    data = client.recv(8192)
    if not data:
        print 'network connection close by client'
        break
    valueList = data.split()

print 'All done, closing child process'
update.join()
activate,join()
```

Comment: What's the error message (with line number)? Also, your last line should be `activate.join()`, not `activate,join()`.

Comment: The obvious step to debug this is to log `valueList` (or at least `len(valueList)` if you expect the whole thing to be too big and horrible to read) inside the `while` loop in `activateRobot`.

Comment: Hold on… You've got a global variable `valueList` in your main process. You're not doing anything to share it (e.g., `multiprocessing.Array`). So the child process gets a copy of the empty list at startup, and it never gets edited in the child process. So it'll always be `[]`. Am I missing something?

Comment: This could be simply debugged by printing the values in valuelist at various points in runtime.

Comment: For the sake of future-compatibility, you should replace `client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)` `client.connect((Host,Port))` with `client = socket.create_connection((Host, Port))`. Besides, you should conform to [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
data = client.recv(8192)
```

receives *up to* 8192 bytes. You are probably getting partial lines. The line doesn't have to be longer than 8192 bytes for this to happen. You just get to read what has arrived over the network so far which might not be whole lines.